# How to draw a Route between two points with GMap.Net in WinForms?

Tags: c#

I am trying to draw a route between the two points that can be used to navigate which means it should follow roads.

```
  GMapOverlay routeOverlay = new GMapOverlay("routeOverlay");
            PointLatLng start = new PointLatLng(47.2666243,11.4026789);
            PointLatLng end = new PointLatLng(48.155004, 11.4717963);
            MapRoute path = OpenStreetMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(start, end, false, false, 15);    
            
            GMapRoute r = new GMapRoute(path.Points, "test_route");
            r.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
            routeOverlay.Routes.Add(r);
            gmap.Overlays.Add(routeOverlay);
```

But when I execute it, `GMapRoute r = new GMapRoute(path.Points, "test_route");` throws a NullReferenceException because path is null and i am quite confused since path has the "start" and "end" values. How can I fix this error?

Comment: what does `OpenStreetMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(start, end, false, false, 15) do if there is no route at that start and end location? I'm looking at your lat long values for start and end, and there is no route available at your start location, or at least not any streets.

Comment: Sorry the first location was faulty, I fixed it. I think it technically should still draw a route tho.